# how to make a html view for all master data view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner on Laravel, its possible to make a html view (view_master.blade.php) for display all master data view, such as users data use this view_master.blade.php ,
students data also use this view_master.blade.php to display data.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You'll need *view partials*. You may Google or watch (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch)

Comment: I means, how to avoid write form code for every master data,

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a menu/navigation bar that is present in all pages (navbar.blade.php).

You may include it on every page just by calling: @extends('navbar').

Hope this simple explanation helps. :)